# Bizarre problem when building an app with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

My problem is really weird and it's not reproduced on my friends PC with the same code ... It even doesn't reproduce on some other project with different code. Anyway I have some thread with empty run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
}
```

In such shape the project builds fine, so I assume that everything with my configuration / tools and etc is ok.
However ... when I change this method to:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
    }
}
```

compilation run with:

> ./gradlew assembleDebug

stucks on:

> > :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

and it **stucks forever** ... I gave it 67 hours and it was still stuck.
When I move this loop from run method to constructor or anywhere else there is no problem and code compiles. **Compilation stucks only when loop is placed in run method.**

**Edit:** the issue is even weirder because when I do:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    boolean x = true;
    while (x) {
    }
}
```

it compiles fine.

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild of your project?

Comment: Which Android Studio version? The release notes for 3.1.4 contains this point regarding a bugfix: _"R8 entered an infinite loop while performing certain optimizations."_ (it's unclear to me when the bug was introduced).

Comment: I've tried cleaning / rebuilding and all of those things. Moreover Android Studio is not the case because I build from terminal.

Comment: _"Moreover Android Studio is not the case because I build from terminal."_ Presumably you're still using command-line tools that come bundled with Android Studio.

Comment: I thought that gradlew is independent. It downloads it's own wrapper and etc. but ok, my Android Studio version is: 3.2 Canary 5